# MagicalRecord importFromObject: JSON with dictionary?

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, magicalrecord

I'm parsing some JSON which comes to me in this format:

```
{
dataId = "823o7tr23d387g";
category = "link";
details = {
    text = "Some text associated with the link";
    url = "http://www.url.com";
    thumbnail_url = "http://www.url.com/picture.jpeg";
};
source = "CNN";
},
{
...
},
```

MagicalRecord has a great importing method: `+ (id) importFromObject:(id)data;` but does it support dictionaries inside the JSON dictionary so that it can automatically map the `details {}` to the appropriate properties?

Is there a naming convention or something I will need to use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out this article about using MagicalRecord to automatically import JSON, specifically the  data keypath support section

http://www.cimgf.com/2012/05/29/importing-data-made-easy/

> **Data Keypath Support**
>
> Key Value Coding is a common and effective tool in Objective C.
>   MagicalImport gives you access to some of this power by allowing you
>   to specify keyPaths as part of a mappedKeyName. If you’re familiar
>   with KVC, this should be a fairly straightforward feature as
>   Magicalmport passed these specified keys to the KVC methods under the
>   covers. Keypath support allows you to map data to an entity that may
>   not have exactly the same hierarchy as the data model. For example, a
>   data entity may store latitude and longitude, but the source data
>   looks more like this:
>
> ```
> {
>   "name": "Point Of Origin",
>   "location":
>   {
>     "latitude": 0.00,
>     "longitude": 0.00
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> In this case, we can specify as our data import key paths,
>   location.latitude and location.longitude in our mappedKeyName
>   configuration to dig into the nested data structure and import those
>   values specifically into our core data entity.

Comment: Thanks, great source. Excuse my ignorance, but I am not 100% sure how I map it. If I have an attribute `detailsText`, in the User Info for this attribute, I have added *Key: `details.text` Value: `id`* but that doesn't map the data, unfortunately.

Comment: You need to look at the userInfo area in your core data model. Click on an entity, or and attribute, and look in the entity inspector. It will appear below the attribute settings. It's a simple key-value table interface.

Comment: Got it! Read the article too fast :) Thanks all!

Answer (score 2):

The blog Scott mentioned is a must read for who use MagicalRecord.

In addition, if the default `+ (id) importFromObject:(id)data` doesn't work on some of your NSDictionary data, you can always override the `- (BOOL) importValuesForKeysWithObject:(id)objectData` method in your NSManagedObject subclass to achieve the exact control over mapping.

Here's a snippet from one of my recent project:

```
// override MagicalRecord's implementation with additional set up for Dialogue relationship
- (BOOL) importValuesForKeysWithObject:(id)objectData {
    BOOL result = [super importValuesForKeysWithObject:objectData];

    // update lesson-dialogue data
    id dialogueDicts = [objectData objectForKey:@"dialogue"];
    if ([dialogueDicts isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
        for (id dialogueDict in dialogueDicts) {
            DialogueSentence *dialogue = [DialogueSentence findFirstByAttribute:@"id" withValue:[[dialogueDict objectForKey:@"id"]];
            if (dialogue == nil) {
                dialogue = [DialogueSentence createEntity];
            }
            [dialogue importValuesForKeysWithObject:dialogueDict];
            [self addDialoguesObject:dialogue];    // connect the relationship
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

By the way, you may want to create a category of your NSManagedObject subclass and write the overriding code there, because when you upgrade your Core Data model version and re-generate the NSManagedObject subclasses, your own code won't be wiped out.

Comment: Not sure why you have to do this. The whole point of magicalimport is that this sort of boilerplate is done for you. Help me understand your need for this so I can correct this in a future version: the@magicalpanda.com

Comment: MagicalRecord has no problem, it's just sometimes I have to deal with projects that were not designed with MagicalRecord in mind at the first place, i.e.: core data attributes are not named properly, relationships are not exactly same as JSON. By the time I ran into situation like this, the blog "Import Data Made Easy" hadn't been written, so I figured it out the hard way. Nevertheless, had I followed the blog by updating the core data model, I would document the changes somewhere, otherwise people would have no idea what's the magic behind the importing.